# Can't get rails_autolink to work in rails 3.2.2

Tags: rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need the function [auto_link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link) in my project.

So I try to install the gem [rails_autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink).

**In the Gemfile:**

`gem 'rails_autolink'`

Then I stop the server, run `bundle install`, start the server.

**In my controller:**

```
require 'rails_autolink'

# ...

auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello to david@loudthinking.com")
```

And I get:

> NoMethodError in Relation::CustomsController#index
>
> undefined method `auto_link' for
>
> In app/controllers/relation/customs_controller.rb:12:in `index'

How do I include rails_autolink properly ?

Edit: `gem install rails_autolink` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `auto_link` is not working because you're calling it in the context of the controller. Try doing

```
class CustomsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
end
```

(If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink/blob/master/lib/rails_autolink/helpers.rb), you'll see that `auto_link` is part of something called `TextHelper`.)

Or, if possible, move the `auto_link` call from the controller to the view. It's view-related logic, anyway.

Comment: I have a page where the user types in a mail with a send button, and I want to parse the links that he may have entered with auto_link (just before sending it to the `mail` function). So I don't know how to move the call to auto_link in the view. Maybe I should use another function ? Or call it only when displaying the mail ?

Comment: Adding `include TextHelper` in my controller does not help.

Comment: I've tried `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  include ApplicationHelper` with still no success.

Comment: I can call `auto_link` in the view, so I think it is likely a "controller context" problem. I just don't know how to make it work in the controller.

Comment: What if you include `RailsAutoLink::ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`?

Comment: I get `uninitialized constant Relation::CustomsController::RailsAutoLink`. But `include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to extract URLs from text, you might be better off with `URI.extract`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855388/199712

Comment: I want to adds tag around links, not extract links. Eg: `"I love the website www.example.com"` should become `"I love the website <a href='www.example.com'>www.example.com</a>"`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this, and want to use a viewHelper outside of a view do this:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.auto_link(text)
```